# Typescript: Prisma relation list field getting error when passed with argument

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I tried to create a new project with Prisma Client, but I'm getting an error when passing it with `args`, even just an empty array list like this `[]`.

this is my prisma model

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Project {
    id String @id @default(cuid())
    name String
    date DateTime @default(now())
    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @default(now())
    type String
    client String?
    images Image[]
}

model Image {
    id String @id @default(cuid())
    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @default(now())
    title String?
    alt String?
    description String?
    src String
    project Project @relation(fields: [projectId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
    projectId String
}
```

and this is my typescript type

```
export interface Project {
    name: string;
    date: Date;
    type: string;
    client: string;
    images?: Image[];
}

export interface Image {
    title: string;
    alt: string;
    description: string;
    src: string;
    projectId?: string;
}
```

this is my mutation

**Attempt 1**

```
createProject: async (args: Project) => {
  const project = await prisma.project.create({
    data: {
      client: args.client,
      date: args.date,
      name: args.name,
      type: args.type,
      images: args.images
    }
  })
}
```

**Attempt 2**

```
createProject: async (args: Project) => {
  const project = await prisma.project.create({
    data: {
      client: args.client,
      date: args.date,
      name: args.name,
      type: args.type,
      images: []
    }
  })
}
```

**Attempt 3**

```
createProject: async (args: Project & { images?: Image[] }) => {
  const project = await prisma.project.create({
    data: {
      client: args.client,
      date: args.date,
      name: args.name,
      type: args.type,
      images: args.images
    }
  })
}
```

and this is the error from the prisma client

`Type 'Image[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ImageUncheckedCreateNestedManyWithoutProjectInput | ImageCreateNestedManyWithoutProjectInput | undefined'. Type 'Image[]' is not assignable to type 'ImageUncheckedCreateNestedManyWithoutProjectInput | ImageCreateNestedManyWithoutProjectInput | undefined'.ts(2322)`

---

`index.d.ts(3077, 5): The expected type comes from property 'images' which is declared here on type '(Without<ProjectCreateInput, ProjectUncheckedCreateInput> & ProjectUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & ProjectCreateInput)' (property) images: Image[] | undefined`

I'm curious about how to generate TypeScript types based on the Prisma model. If you guys have any best practices, I'd appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the types from Prisma directly after you run `npx prisma generate`

```
import { Image, Project } from "@prisma/client"
```

If you open the file where they are defined in, you can get more detailed types for your models.

`node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts`

There are a lot of types inside this file, you just have to find the ones you need for specific uses.

Comment: OMG, thank you @SlothOverlord! I just found out.